# PHP Form result to Dompdf PDF

Tags: php, dompdf

I am trying to export the results of a form generated by PHP to PDF through DOMPDF. But its generating a blank page. May be the generated HTML has some issues.

PHP Script is as follows. Iam just pasting the HTML output here since the PHP file is long and has lots of functions. so i guess its a problem with HTML formatting:

```
<?php 
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Country Language</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php ob_start(); ?>
<form>
<table border="1"><tr><td><b>Countries Selected</b></td><td><b>Details</b></td><td><b>Amount</b></td></tr>  
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='8'><h2>Australia</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Z</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Entity</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;N</td>
        <td>&nbsp;0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>English to English</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;X</td>
        <td>&nbsp;1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Y</td>
        <td>&nbsp;2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>TOTAL PATENT FEE</strong></td>
        <td><b>&nbsp;USD&nbsp;1400.45</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='8'><h2>India</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Z</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Entity</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Micro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;N</td>
        <td>&nbsp;1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Arabic to English</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;X</td>
        <td>&nbsp;1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Y</td>
        <td>&nbsp;2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>TOTAL PATENT FEE</strong></td>
        <td><b>&nbsp;USD&nbsp;315.45</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>



<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['pdf'] ) ) {
  $html = ob_get_contents();
  $html = ob_get_clean();
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
  $dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream("the_inquiry.pdf");
}
?>
<div class="shouldPrintToPDF">
    <a  href="/general/cean/cost-calc5.php?&amp;pdf=1" class="pdflink">Open as PDF</a>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

THE PHP SCRIPT IS AS FOLLOWS:

```
<?php
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;


    if (isset($_GET['pdf'])) {
    ob_start(); 
}
else {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Country Language</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>



<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$language_selected = $_POST['language'];
$claims_selected = $_POST['claims'];
$pages_selected = $_POST['pages'];
$totalwords_selected = $_POST['totalwords'];
$claims_selected = $_POST['claims'];
$entity_selected1 = $_POST['entity_selected'];


//echo '<div class="container">';
echo '<form>';

        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><td><b>Countries Selected</b></td><td><b>Fee Details</b></td><td><b>Amount</b></td></tr>';

            foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $key => $country_checked) {

                if(!empty($_POST['entity_selected'][$key])) {
                $entity_selected = $_POST['entity_selected'][$key];
                } else {
                $entity_selected = '';
                }

            $sql_db = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id, country, language, entity FROM country_languages where country = '$country_checked' ");
            //$row_db = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_db);
                while($row_db = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_db)) {
                    $id = $row_db["id"];
                    $country = $row_db["country"];
                    $language = $row_db["language"];
                    $entity = $row_db["entity"];
                        if ($language_selected == $language) {
                         $Z = '0';
                        } else {
                         $Z = $totalwords_selected;
                        }
                             if ($entity_selected =='') {
                                $N = '0';
                             } else if ($entity_selected == 'Micro') {
                                $N = '1';
                             } else if (($entity_selected == 'Small') AND ($country_checked == 'India')) {
                                $N = '2.2';
                             }  else if (($entity_selected == 'Small') AND ($country_checked !== 'India')) {
                                $N = '2';
                             } else if (($entity_selected == 'Large') AND ($country_checked == 'India')) {
                                $N = '4.4';
                             } else if (($entity_selected == 'Large') AND ($country_checked == 'Philippines')) {
                                $N = '5.5';
                             } else if (($entity_selected == 'Large') AND ($country_checked !== 'Philippines') AND ($country_checked !== 'India')) {
                                $N = '4';
                             } else {
                                $N = '0';
                             }
                            $X = $claims_selected;
                            $Y = $pages_selected;
                        if ($country_checked == 'USA') {
                        $result = (430 + 25 * ($X - 20) + 200 * (($Y - 100) / 50 + (1 - ($Y - 100) / 50))) * $N + 0.15 * $Z + 750;  
                        } else {
                        $result = 'Not able to fetch data.';
                        }

?>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='8'><h2><?php echo $country_checked; ?></h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Z</td>
        <td><?php echo $Z; ?></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Entity</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $entity_selected; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;N</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $N; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $language_selected; ?> to <?php echo $language; ?></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;X</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $X; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Y</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $Y; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>TOTAL PATENT FEE</strong></td>
        <td><b>&nbsp;USD&nbsp;<?php echo number_format((float)$result, 2, '.', ''); ?></b></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}   // END WHILE LOOP   
    } //END FOR LOOP
echo '</table>';
}

?>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['pdf'])) {
  $html = ob_get_clean();
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
  $dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream("the_inquiry.pdf");
} 

else {
?>
<div class="shouldPrintToPDF">
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] , '?' , http_build_query( $_GET ); ?>&amp;pdf=1" class="pdflink">Open or save as PDF</a>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php }  }?>
```

Comment: While it is not strongly connected to the question your code IS VULNERABLE TO SQL INJECTION ATTACKS! Please check out mysqli prepared statements and use them. Your code IS VULNERABLE TO CROSS-SITE SCRIPTING attacks as well because you don't escape data that you got from the URL (eg.: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`).

Comment: You only generate the table when a POST request was made and the data is available to generate the table. When you click on the PDF link a GET request is made. You can solve it by sending and receiving data with GET instead of POST. (eg.: $_POST['language'] => $_GET['language']). Another solution is to replace the PDF link with a form (it can be an invisible form with hidden input fields) that sends the necessary data.

Comment: Okay. Can you provide me a sample for to replace the PDF link with an invisible form

Comment: I've updated my answer with a little example. I hope it helps you!

Comment: There are so many loops which is generating the fields or form results. Anyways thank you for the help. Really appreciate your time.

Comment: Maybe an even simpler solution would be to replace all `$_POST` with `$_REQUEST` and replace `http_build_query($_GET)` with `http_build_query($_POST)` in the PDF link (but in that case the URL could be very long).  Sidenote: Make sure you sanitize all of the user input with `htmlspecialchars()` that you use in HTML.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i replaces all POST to GET and its working fine with some tweaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you output HTML content even when the pdf query string exists in the URL. The generated PDF will be mixed with HTML so it becomes invalid. You shouldn't send any HTML code to the browser when you send the PDF. Here is a possible solution with conditionals:

```php
<?php 
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

if (isset($_GET['pdf'])) {
    ob_start(); 
}
else {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Country Language</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<?php } ?>
<table border="1"><tr><td><b>Countries Selected</b></td><td><b>Details</b></td><td><b>Amount</b></td></tr>  
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='8'><h2>Australia</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Z</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Entity</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;N</td>
        <td>&nbsp;0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>English to English</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;X</td>
        <td>&nbsp;1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Y</td>
        <td>&nbsp;2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>TOTAL PATENT FEE</strong></td>
        <td><b>&nbsp;USD&nbsp;1400.45</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='8'><h2>India</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Z</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Entity</td>
        <td>&nbsp;Micro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;N</td>
        <td>&nbsp;1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Arabic to English</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;X</td>
        <td>&nbsp;1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Y</td>
        <td>&nbsp;2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>TOTAL PATENT FEE</strong></td>
        <td><b>&nbsp;USD&nbsp;315.45</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>



<?php
if (isset($_GET['pdf'])) {
  $html = ob_get_clean();
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
  $dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream("the_inquiry.pdf");
}
else {
?>
<div class="shouldPrintToPDF">
    <a href="/general/cean/cost-calc5.php?&amp;pdf=1" class="pdflink">Open as PDF</a>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```

You only generate the table when a POST request was made and the data is available to generate the table. When you click on the PDF link a GET request is made. You can solve it by sending and receiving data with GET instead of POST. (eg.: $_POST['language'] => $_GET['language']). Another solution is to replace the PDF link with a form (it can be an invisible form with hidden input fields) that sends the necessary data. You should also delete other `<form>` and `</form>` tags from the page(I think they are unnecessary).

```php
<?php
function repopulate($field) {

    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[$field]);
    }
}
?>
<div class="shouldPrintToPDF">
    <form method="post" action="?pdf=1">
        <input type="hidden" name="language" value="<?php repopulate('language'); ?>">
        <!-- Add all your fields (claims, pages...) here and use the repopulate function -->
        <button name="submit" type="submit">Open or save as PDF</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me test it out with my actual PHP script.

Comment: the script is not working when i embed in my actual PHP file. But your script is fine. Is their another other approach. If you want i can send my PHP code, if you can help me to embed this.

Comment: What do you mean about "not working"? Could you tell me what error you get? You can show your entire script. There are many approaches, but I think the best solution would be to use a template engine like Twig to render HTML content. Your code would be much cleaner.

Comment: I am modifying and adding the PHP script for your reference. I am getting blank page when i click the generate PDF link.